# Teradata wildcard join with modifying table instead of conditions

Tags: sql, teradata

I have **tablea** and **tableb**, that I need to join.

It can happen that in `b.col2`, `b.col3` can be value '%', which should be something like wildcard, meaninng, that in this case we can join value of `b.col2` on any value of `a.col2` or value `b.col3` on any value `a.col3`.

One solution would look like this:

```
select a.*, b.col4, b.col5
from tablea a 
left join (select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 tableb) b
 on b.col1=a.col1 and
 (b.col2 = a.col2 or b.col2 = '%') and
 (b.col3 = a.col3 or b.col3 = '%')
qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by a.id order by (case when b.col2 = '%' then 2 else 1 end), (case when b.col3 = '%' then 2, else 1 end))
```

My problem is that because of later use in different app, I can only use simple join conditions like:

```
  b.col1 = a.col1 and
  b.col2 = a.col2 and
  b.col3 = a.col3
```

My question is, if there is a way, how to achieve the same result as in the first solution, but using 'simple' join conditions (a.col2=b.col2) and just making changes in selection of `tableb`?

Comment: "My problem is that because of later use in different app, I can only use simple join conditions like:"  I just don't get this.  Why would an app care what a query looks like?  You can just create a view with this query, for instance.  Also, your method is not the most efficient, but that is not what you are asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , thanks for your reply. I need it for Informatica BDM lookup transformation. For various reasons, I cannot use joiner transformation instead. The problem is, that in the lookup transformation I can only use 'simple' conditions for the join. But I can edit the query for lookup table, which is tableb. Anyway, can you provide me with more effective way of my first solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JanFi86 Gordon's point still stands. You create a view in Teradata with this SQL you have and you have informatica do a `SELECT * FROM your_new_view;` There's no reason to have Informatica hold all of this complicated RDBMS specific logic. This is something that we do as a matter of standard process. If we are going to extract from Teradata we create a view (even it's a straight select) then the ETL tool pulls from that view. The nice thing here is that if you need to change the logic a year from now, you merely edit the view without touching Informatica.

Comment: From a security standpoint I would give the username that Informatica uses to connect access to only a single database and it's in that database where I would build the view. Then authorization can be given to the database to select from other databases and tables. This will trap informatica into a single database and insure that it's not just willy-nilly extracting from everywhere. It's very clear then which applications (informatica) has access to what data (tables and views in its database).

Comment: Thank you all for replies and suggestions. My situation is, that I need to have  it dynamic in a sense, that I can have 1 to 5 columns that are part of the joining conditions connected or not connected, so I cannot use view